# Copy file to a location till drive is full - then divert to new location

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking to render PDF files then move them to a folder location. Once there: I want the script to monitor the drive space.

1) When it drops below a threshold - keep copying files but to a new location.

2) When the threshold drops below a certain percentage of the overall drive space - keep copying files but to a new location.

The while statement does not update the new value of the drive space after each copy is completed. Therefore the statement stays True till the drive runs out.

I've tried:

```
while True:
        if  space.free > 3500000:
```

and also:

```
while space.free > 3500000:
```

neither is working.

```
import shutil

space = shutil.disk_usage(r"z:")

num = 1

while True:
    if  space.free > 3500000:
        filemame = "Test_PDF " + str(num) + ".pdf"
        shutil.copy(r"C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\Test_PDF.pdf", r"Z:" + filemame)
        num += 1
        print(space.free)
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.disk_usage` returns the usage info for the disk at the point in time when it is called. It does not setup some sort of constantly updating result. Specifically, it returns a tuple and tuples cannot be updated. Try moving the call into the loop:

```py
while True:
   space = shutil.disk_usage(r"z:")
   if space.free > 3500000:
```

Comment: That worked! Next part... why :) I know it returns a tuple but I wasn't updating that value - I was recalling the object off that tuple to get an updated value in the loop (space.free). So how come each time that was called it didn't re-assess and get an updated response?

Comment: The result of the `disk_usage` call is a named tuple, so basically a tuple with a name for each index. `free` is a name for one of the values within the tuple. It refers to a specific number and that number will never change.

Comment: Another way to think about it is `disk_usage` is what does the assessment and it does the assessment immediately when called. The results of doing that assessment at that point in time are what is returned by the call.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua - appreciate the assist

Comment: My pleasure! Please accept my answer when you get the chance if it answered your questions :)